# Can ADC take discrete signals as input?

Tags: adc, signal

Generally we give analog signal to ADC as input. As per my understanding, `ADC` has sample and hold circuit before voltage comparator. This sample and hold circuit samples the analog signal and hold for sometime. Here the signal may resemble like discrete signal. Now my question is that as input to ADC, can we give a discrete signal directly. If we give discrete signal as input, what properties we need to consider for the signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A discreet signal i.e. one that has potentially near-instantaneous changes in amplitude will contain signal harmonics that may easily be beyond the Nyquist frequency of the ADCs sampling rate. On this basis alone some form of aliasing will occur and your digitized signal will be noisier than had you fed your discreet signal via an anti-alias filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can input such a signal directly into an ADC without a problem **as long as** the changes in level are synchronised to the conversion sequence of the ADC, as if the signal had been generated by a sample and hold properly phased for that ADC.